# Lagging of the run() method are to strong

Tags: multithreading, try-catch, sleep, runnable, milliseconds

```
    private static int millis_per_tick = 1;
    public void run() 
    {   
      // While not stop do
      while(true) 
      {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        long startTime, timeTaken;          
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        act();
        timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if(timeTaken < millis_per_tick )
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(millis_per_tick-timeTaken );
            }

            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {}

        }
```

The thread.sleep method does not accept double values only float and integer. But i need a value under 1.

In Space

```
public void act() 
{
    ListIterator<Body> iterator = bodies.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Body body = iterator.next();
        body.wirkenKraefte();
        body.move();
    }
    spaceGUI.repaint();
```

Comment: i must better say that if i change millis per tick from 0 to 1 the act() -method(repaint and calculating position) are very slowly

Comment: i have just noticed that i have in my act method a while() - method i edit my question with the act method

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Thread.sleep(long,int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) method in the API.

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds **plus the specified number of nanoseconds**.

Comment: Yup, I've only just seen that myself and edited into my answer - but note that it depends on the precision of the system clock, and I would expect *most* systems to fail to sleep for sub-millisecond periods.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. 1ms is even more than 1ms (15.6ms) and this is not guranteed.

-> [Can I improve the resolution of Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614936/can-i-improve-the-resolution-of-thread-sleep/7614989#7614989)

Answer (score 0):

You can't sleep for less than a millisecond using `Thread.sleep(long)` - and on many platforms, you'll find that even sleeping for one millisecond will *actually* sleep for longer (e.g. 15 milliseconds) depending on the granularity of the system clock.

In other words, you basically can't do what you're trying to do with `Thread.sleep(long)` - and trying to get a sub-millisecond precision time is troublesome in the first place. You can try using [`System.nanoTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) instead, which is *only* appropriate for elapsed times (so fine in this case) - and you *might* want to consider a spin-lock to wait until the right time, instead of sleeping.

In most cases it's a bad idea to even *try* to execute something at a fixed rate of 1000 calls per second though... what's the use case here? There may be a better approach.

EDIT: I've just noticed that there *is* [`Thread.sleep(millis, nanos)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29) - you could *try* using this and sleep for (say) 0 milliseconds and 100,000 nanoseconds. You should be aware that *on most platforms* this won't actually do what you want though. You can try it for your particular use case, but I wouldn't personally hold out too much hope.

Comment: ok my use case is that i have an space with two planets. In my act() method it calculate his new position with an vector than it make a repaint.

Comment: @Mr.Knister: And why do you need to do that 1000 times per second? Surely you won't be able to display it that often anyway...

Comment: hmm.. you right but if i change millis per tick at 0 it works very well but i want change the speed with changing of the millis per tick
but if i change it to 1 it stops/goes very slow

Comment: @Mr.Knister: That's basically because it's the difference between "not sleeping at all" and "sleeping between each tick". You need to work out what your *real* requirements are. You shouldn't really be blocking the UI thread like this anyway to be honest...

Comment: this program should be sleep on every stage that means calculating-->repaint-->sleep-->calculating... i hope i understand the question :) Sorry

Comment: @Mr.Knister: But you still shouldn't block the UI thread by making it sleep. Instead, you should schedule a timer for the UI thread to call into your recalculation task. Otherwise you're stopping all the other UI operations from occurring.

Comment: Could you please a simple programm code for a schedule timmer please?

Comment: @Mr.Knister: Not easily, especially as your question doesn't tell us *anything* about the context - is this in Android, Swing, etc?

Comment: I am programming with Eclipse and create the gui with eclipse plugin jiggloo (java.swing) is that what you mean?

Comment: @Mr.Knister: Okay, it sounds like a Swing UI then. (It would have been worth stating that and the programming language in the question.) Look at `javax.swing.Timer`.