# Timeout and stop a Task

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have a console app,

```
        {
            StartThread();
            //must be true, windows system wants to know it is started
            return true;
        }
```

I'm trying to create a safety timeout function for this Task. But the task keeps running...

The method DoSomething calls other async methods and awaits their result

Do anyone have an idea why my task don't stop? Maybe a good code example on what to do

```
  public async void StartThread()
        {
             var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = tokenSource.Token;
                try
                {
                        var timeout = 1000;
                        Task task = new Task(() => DoSomething(token), token);
                        task.Start();

                        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, token)) == task)
                        {
                            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                                task.Dispose();

                            await task;

                            if (task.IsCompleted)
                            {
                                task.Dispose();
                                tokenSource.Cancel();
                                tokenSource.Dispose();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                log.WriteToFile("Timeout_ ");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            tokenSource.Cancel();
                   }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("--StartThread ...there is an exception----");
                }
                finally
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(300000); // 5 minutter
                    StartThread();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645899/awaiting-task-with-timeout

Comment: What does `DoSomething` do with the `CancellationToken`?

Comment: DoSomething starts with cheking if it has been cancelled, after that i calls 2 other methods` public async Task<bool> DoSomething(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            var success = false;
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)            
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            List<int> list = new List<int>();
                list = await GetShopList();
                if (list.Count > 0)                                 
                    success = await GetReport(token_, list);    
            return success;
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not create `CancellationTokenSource` from given `timeout`?

```
var timeout = 1000;

//DONE: don't forget to dispose CancellationTokenSource instance 
using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout)) {
  try {
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    //TODO: May be you'll want to add .ConfigureAwait(false);
    Task task = Task.Run(() => DoSomething(token), token);

    await task;

    // Completed
  }
  catch (TaskCanceledException) {
    // Cancelled due to timeout

    log.WriteToFile("Timeout_ ");
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    // Failed to complete due to e exception

    Console.WriteLine("--StartThread ...there is an exception----");

    //DONE: let's be nice and don't swallow the exception
    throw; 
  }
}
```

Comment: the tasks runnning in DoSomething method keeps running after the task is cancelled, how can i make them stop?

Comment: @Lise: Cancellation is *cooperative* in .Net; you should change / update `DoSomething` method; typical solution is to throw `TaskCanceledException` via `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` call

Answer (score 0):

You should hardly ever `Dispose` a `Task`, since iot is managed by C# internals and it is taken care of. Also, you `Dispose` way too eagerly, for example:

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    task.Dispose();

await task;
```

I do not think so you want still await task if it **cancelled** and **disposed**. I guess it will not work at all.

Also if you use `async`, do not mix blocking calls such as `Thread.Sleep` - that can lead to disaster...

After all, you use cancellation token with some delay task to imitate a timeout - that's OK, but why do put unnecessary code, when you have great API at hand. Just make use of special contructor of `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
public CancellationTokenSource (int millisecondsDelay);
```

[Here's the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_Int32_)

Comment: well the reason i use thread.sleep in the finally is beacuse the task must wait 5 minutes before running again

Comment: If you're looking to schedule tasks, there are better ways to do it than sleeping for 5 minutes. Use a library like Hangfire for example.

Comment: @Lise you can use `await Task.Delay(5 * 60 * 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

After a timeout you are setting the `CancellationToken` and then immediately sleeping the thread for 5 minutes. Thus `DoSomething()` never gets a chance to continue running and react to the token being cancelled.