# Why is time.sleep() accuracy influenced by Chrome?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sleep, lag

I've noticed some strange behaviour that may or may not be specific to my system. (lenovo t430 running windows 8)

**With this script:**

```
import time

now = time.time()
while True:
    then = now
    now = time.time()
    dif = now - then
    print(dif)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

I get the following output (what I would consider nominal) with a browser open.

[image]

However without a browser open I observe a severe per loop latency.

[image]

Obviously this is counter-intuitive as I think anyone would expect better performance when you have fewer concurrant processes.

Any insights or simple replication of these results would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Interestingly I observe similar latency with this code:

```
import time

now = time.time()

def newSleep(mark,duration):
    count = 0
    while time.time()-mark < duration:
        count+=1
    print(count)


while True:
    then = now
    now = time.time()
    dif = now - then
    print(dif)
    #time.sleep(0.01)
    newSleep(now,0.01)
```

While it does provide additional insight - that is some instances of latent loops are due to lack of processor availability (noted by a count of 0 being printed)- I still notice the 15ms behavior where the printed count will be as high as 70k... and 10ms behavior with counts around 40k.

Comment: Is the browser actually doing something, like displaying animation? If it's idle, it shouldn't have much effect on performance.

Comment: I don't think this benchmark is enough to make any sort of conclusions.

Comment: It's hard to say. There are certainly instances of the increased latency while the browser is open (for example right now with just SO open I'm watching it bounce back and forth as I type) however with gmail open I get fairly consistent "fast" loops.

As I move my mouse around over a browser it performs nominally. When the user input stops I observe latancy...

Comment: I have tested the same code on my machine and tried opening and closing different processes. Can't seem to find any differences in the time of each iteration.

Comment: But I don't think that I am putting enough pressure on my CPU cores.

Comment: See that's the strange bit... my cpu is only running at like 2% it shouldn't be choking like this.

Comment: Perhaps this plays a role: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling

Comment: Note that *it is the `time.sleep(..)` duration being measured*, and *not* actual load-work being done (the loop is written in a way that obscures this, although it can be trivially updated to make it more clear). From a system viewpoint, sleeping takes no CPU resources. I've updated the title to reflect.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19415153/2864740

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I extra fired up Windows 7 to replicate your findings and I can confirm it.

It's a [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/time) thing with the type of timer used and a default resolution of 15.6 ms (minimum 0.5 ms). Applications can alter the current resolution (WinAPI function: [timeBeginPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod)) and Chrome does so.

> This function affects a global Windows setting. Windows uses the
>   lowest value (that is, highest resolution) requested by any process.
>   Setting a higher resolution can improve the accuracy of time-out
>   intervals in wait functions. However, it can also reduce overall
>   system performance, because the thread scheduler switches tasks more
>   often. High resolutions can also prevent the CPU power management
>   system from entering power-saving modes. Setting a higher resolution
>   does not improve the accuracy of the high-resolution performance
>   counter.

An article from 2014 in [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ianmorris/2014/07/14/googles-chrome-web-browser-is-killing-your-laptop-battery/) is covering a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411592) in Chrome which would set the resolution *permanently* to 1 ms no matter what current load would require - a problem because it's a system-wide effect with impact on energy consumption. From that article:

> In an OS like Windows, events are often set to run at intervals. To
>   save power, the processor sleeps when nothing needs attention, and
>   wakes at predefined intervals. This interval is what Chrome adjusts in
>   Windows, so reducing it to 1.000ms means that the system is waking far
>   more often than at 15.625ms. In fact, at 1.000ms the processor is
>   waking 1000 times per second. The default, of 15.625ms means the
>   processor wakes just 64 times per second to check on events that need
>   attention.
>
> Microsoft itself says that tick rates of 1.000ms might increase power
>   consumption by "as much as 25 per cent".

You can get the default resolution from Python with [time.get_clock_info()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.get_clock_info).

```
namespace = time.get_clock_info('time')
namespace.adjustable
# True
namespace.implementation
# 'GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()'
namespace.monotonic
# False
namespace.resolution
# 0.015600099999999999
```

You can get the actual resolution from `cmd` with the [ClockRes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/clockres) applet.

Comment: Running the same script in Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 5.0.0) tells `1e-09`!

Comment: So I assume it is a different concept in Linux. Otherwise, power consumption would be crazy ...

Comment: I googled and found some answers ([tickless Linux kernel](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2012/09/tickless-linux-kernels.html), and [tickless kernel @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tickless_kernel)])

Answer (score 8):

I tried the same within both windows and ubuntu server(virtualbox)(which doen't have a browser) but the result's are same which average i am getting

in Ubuntu Server

```
    0.010122537612915039
    0.010426998138427734
    0.010067939758300781
    0.010767221450805664
    0.010728120803833008
    0.010106086730957031
    0.01068258285522461
    0.010105609893798828
    0.01118612289428711
    0.010136842727661133
    0.010585784912109375
    0.010425567626953125
    0.01014852523803711
    0.010422945022583008
    0.01010894775390625
```

and in Windows

```
    0.010767221450805664
    0.010751485824584961
    0.010716915130615234
    0.010229110717773438
    0.01016545295715332
    0.010195255279541016
    0.010723352432250977
    0.010744094848632812
    0.010716438293457031
    0.010564565658569336
    0.010889291763305664
    0.010728597640991211
    0.010579824447631836
    0.010889530181884766
    0.010567903518676758
    0.010717153549194336
    0.010735273361206055
```

so, in my opinion, there is no correlation between the opened browser and performance of python

Answer (score 6):

> Any insights or simple replication of these results would be appreciated.

Here you go:

Using your code and the most recent release of Chrome, I can confirm this behaviour with nearly the same results.

I measured the average time taken-

Browser running: 0.01055538261329734

Browser not running: 0.01563055389053695

I have about 30 open tabs, but they are all idle. Currently, I can't think of any reason why this would happen.

Looking forward to further insights.

Answer (score 6):

While I cannot reproduce this behavior on my machine, my suspicion is that it can be caused by dynamic processor clock (as well as memory and system bus clocks), e.g. when you don't have a browser open then processor is running at 1/2 of maximum clock, but once you start a browser it gets to a maximum clock. You can verify this by playing with "Maximum\minimum processor state\frequency" in Advanced Power Options or by running another application that spawns many processes (this is what Chrome does) instead of a browser and see if this changes the latency.

Comment: That possibility occurred to me however I observed the latent and nominal behavior at a variety of clock rates. 1.2 - 3.x ghz

Comment: Have you tried to spawn multiple processes with a different apllication(s) and check the latency?

Comment: I think you are right. There is a lot variables involved how the kernel scheduler works is complex

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a similar code and got similar outputs,

```
for i in range(10):
    then = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    now = time.time()
    # print('+---------------------------+')
    print(now - then)
    # print(f"rounded: {round(now - then, 2)}")
    # print('+---------------------------+')
```

I first suspected that what is causing this is, is the usage of floating point math [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

But then I got this output

**Outputs**

```
0.01080012321472168
0.01015472412109375
0.010109186172485352
0.022491931915283203 # THIS ONE IS REALLY WEIRD
0.01163029670715332
0.010137796401977539
0.010179996490478516
0.01008749008178711
0.010132551193237305
0.010088443756103516
```

Even if you assumed that there are a margin of error in calculating the difference, it shouldn't be that much

```
+---------------------------+
0.01080012321472168
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.01015472412109375
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.010109186172485352
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.022491931915283203
rounded: 0.02                 
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.01163029670715332
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.010137796401977539
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.010179996490478516
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.01008749008178711
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.010132551193237305
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
0.010088443756103516
rounded: 0.01
+---------------------------+
```

But after reading python's official documentation of the `time.sleep` method, these results make sense [check here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), I quote the documentation

> the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system

So as an educated guess of the problem here,

It is being caused by multiple factors

1. Operating system's thread scheduling
2. Execution time before and after the sleep
3. And, Floating-Point calculation.

I hope this helped.